# mongodb upsert doesn't update if locked

Tags: c++, mongodb, upsert

I have an app written in C++ with 16 threads which reads from the output of wireshark/tshark. Wireshark/tshark dissects pcap files which are gsm_map signalling captures.

Mongodb is 2.6.7

The structure I need for my documents are like this:

Note "packet" is an array, it will become apparent why later.

For all who don't know TCAP, the TCAP layer is transaction-oriented, this means, all packets include:

- Transaction State: begin/continue/end
- Origin transaction ID (otid)
- Destination transaction ID (dtid)

So for instance, you might see a transaction comprising 3 packets, which looking at the TCAP layer would be roughly this

Two packets, one "begin", one "end".

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54ccd186b8ea19c89ee8f231"),
    "deleted" : "0",
    "packet" : {
        "datetime" : ISODate("2015-01-31T12:58:11.939Z"),
        "signallingType" : "M2PA",
        "opc" : "326",
        "dpc" : "6406",
        "transState" : "begin",
        "otid" : "M2PA0400435B",
        "dtid" : "",
        "sccpCalling" : "523332075100",
        "sccpCalled" : "523331466304",
        "operation" : "mo-forwardSM (46)",
        ...
    }
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54ccd1a1b8ea19c89ee8f7c5"),
    "deleted" : "0",
    "packet" : {
        "datetime" : ISODate("2015-01-31T12:58:16.788Z"),
        "signallingType" : "M2PA",
        "opc" : "6407",
        "dpc" : "326",
        "transState" : "end",
        "otid" : "",
        "dtid" : "M2PA0400435B",
        "sccpCalling" : "523331466304",
        "sccpCalled" : "523332075100",
        "operation" : "Not Found",
        ...
    }
}
```

Because of the network architecture, we're tracing in two (2) points, and the traffic is balanced amongst these two points. This means sometimes we see "continue"s or "end"s BEFORE a "begin". Conversely, we might see a "continue" BEFORE a "begin" or "end". In short, transactions are *not* ordered.

Moreover, multiple end-points are "talking" amongst themselves, and transactionIDs might get duplicated, 2 endpoints could be using the same tid and other 2 endpoints at the same time, though this doesn't happen all the time, it *does* happen.

Because of the later, I also need to use the SCCP layer's "calling" and "called" Global titles (like phone numbers).

Bear in mind that I don't know which way a given packet is going, so this is what I'm doing:

- Whenever I get a new packet I must find whether the transaction already exists in mongodb, I'm using upsert to do this.

  - I do this by searching the current's packet otid or dtid in either otid or dtid of existing packets
  - If it does: push the new packet into the existing document.
  - If it doesn't: create a new document with the packet.

As an example, this is a upsert for an "end" which should find a "begin":

```
db.runCommand(
  {
    update: "packets",
    updates: 
      [ 
          { q: 
                  { $and: 
                      [ 
                          { 
                              $or: [ 
                                  { "packet.otid": 
                                      { $in: [ "M2PA042e3918" ] } 
                                  }, 
                                  { "packet.dtid": 
                                      { $in: [ "M2PA042e3918" ] } 
                                  } 
                              ] 
                          }, 
                          { 
                              $or: [ 
                                  { "packet.sccpCalling": 
                                      { $in: [ "523332075151", "523331466305" ] }
                                  }, 
                                  { "packet.sccpCalled": 
                                      { $in: [ "523332075151", "523331466305" ] }
                                  } 
                              ] 
                          } 
                      ] 
                  }, 
              { 
                  $setOnInsert: { 
                      "unique-id": "422984b6-6688-4782-9ba1-852a9fc6db3b", deleted: "0" 
                  }, 
                  $push: { 
                      packet: { 
                          datetime: new Date(1422371239182), 
                          opc: "327", dpc: "6407", 
                          transState: "end", 
                          otid: "", dtid: "M2PA042e3918", sccpCalling: "523332075151", ...  }
                  } 
              }, 
              upsert: true 
          } 
    ], 
    writeConcern: { j: "1" }
  }
)
```

Now, all of this works, until I put it in production.

It seems packets are coming way to fast and I see lots of:

"ClientCursor::staticYield Can't Unlock B/c Of Recursive Lock" Warnings 
I read that we can ignore this warning, but I've found that my upserts DO NOT update the documents! It looks like there's a lock and mongodb forgets about the update. If I change the upsert to a simple insert, no packets are lost

I also read this is related to no indexes being used, I have the following index:

```
"3" : {
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "packet.otid" : 1,
        "packet.dtid" : 1,
        "packet.sccpCalling" : 1,
        "packet.sccpCalled" : 1
    },
    "name" : "packet.otid_1_packet.dtid_1_packet.sccpCalling_1_packet.sccpCalled_1",
    "ns" : "tracer.packets"
```

So in conclusion:

1.- If this index is not correct, can someone please help me creating the correct index?
2.- Is it normal that mongo would NOT update a document if it finds a lock?

Thanks and regards!

David

Answer (score 0):

Why are you storing all of the packets in an array? Normally in this kind of situation it's better to make each packet a document on its own; it's hard to say more without more information about your use case (or, perhaps, more knowledge of all these acronyms you're using :D). Your updates would become inserts and you would not need to do the update query. Instead, some other metadata on a packet would join related packets together so you could reconstruct a transaction or whatever you need to do.

More directly addressing your question, I would use an array field `tids` to store `[otid, dtid]` and an array field `sccps` to store `[sccpCalling, sccpCalled]`, which would make your update query look like

```
{ "tids" : { "$in" : ["M2PA042e3918"] }, "sccps" : { "$in" : [ "523332075151", "523331466305" ] } }
```

and amenable to the index `{ "tids" : 1, "sccps" : 1 }`.

Comment: I will try the array suggestion on tids. Regarding the fact that I want to create the transaction on the fly: it0s what I need to do, we're talking MILLIONS of packets per hour, if I wait to associate them (create the transaction later) I think that would pu an extra load on the server. Furthermore,my other question was: is it normal for mongodb to NOT update/insert a document when it finds a (long?) lock?

Comment: No, that is not normal. What do the non-update statements return? Timeouts? Errors of some sort? Can you post a full error message?

Comment: Nothing at all, either "updateExisting: true" if( updated ) or an ObjectId (which is the new inserted object)... I do see in the log a  "Client Cursor::yield can't unlock b/c of recursive lock" exactly when a packet is not inserted/updated.

Comment: Not possible to create that index... http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/ I got an error: "cannot index parallel arrays "

Comment: I don't think it's clear it's not updating if it's not returning an error. How do you know the update isn't happening? Do you have an example? Also, my bad on that index. You can't create compound indexes with > 1 multikey component since the rate of growth of leaf keys is super-linear in that case. You may have to try and live with an index just on one of the arrays I suggested. How selective would such an index be? Tolerable?

Comment: Need to be deterministic, and shouldn't match more than one document... I did have examples, but I need to get them again, will take a while, please bear with me... :)